# How to play original Oddworld games in 1080p?

Tags: pc, windows, oddworld-abes-exoddus, oddworld-abes-oddysee

I've been playing both Oddworld: Abe's Oddysee and Oddworld: Abe's Exoddus for years now, but I'm having some display issues on my new computer. The games didn't run in a proper resolution, after some digging I found the [DirectDraw Hack](https://community.pcgamingwiki.com/files/file/647-oddworld-abes-oddysee-resolution-mod/) and tried it out. The problem with this is that even the DirectDraw Hack doesn't work. Are there any other work-arounds for this?

Comment: Is there an option in game or on your OS for borderless window? Are you using a laptop? ;\ The hack is "to make the games use desktop resolution when in fullscreen". Probably only when it's in *real* FS mode... There's always ePSXe

Comment: Not in game, but I'll need to check the OS. I'm fairly certain the game already runs in fullscreen mode. The resolution fit just fine on on older computers.

Comment: "This method will only raise output resolution to match desktop's one, game will still render at 640x480" So why bother? Does it not fill the screen? That's up to your video card's scaling ability (scaling is on, right?)

Comment: The game doesn't fill the screen. It's almost in letterbox format. I would imagine that my laptop could render the resolution properly, as these are the only games with problems and I have a very powerful gaming laptop.

Comment: AMD or nVidia? Scaling = on. Preserve aspect = off. Stretch to fit/fill screen = on. Try different DT resolutions until it does fit, because it doesn't really matter until you drop below the game's native res. The game renders in 4:3, you have to convince your vid card to scale that to 16:9. (the DD hack might be working against you, if you try to just get your vid card to handle it all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried DxWnd?

It's a program which can be used to run games at arbitrary resolutions.

https://sourceforge.net/p/dxwnd/home/Home/

Comment: Yes, I actually came across it a while ago. I had forgotten that I had this question posted, thanks for the tip anyways.